# How to ignore case when sorting a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activeadmin

When I sort the `name` column of a model in `ActiveAdmin`, I get output such as the following:

- Apples
- Icicles
- Zebras
- iMacs
- iPhones

where the uppercase and lowercase letters appear to be sorted separately. I prefer to display sorted columns in the following manner:

- Apples
- Icicles
- iMacs
- iPhones
- Zebras

with no unnatural case sensitivity. I tried using the line

```
column :name, sortable: 'my_model.name.downcase'
```

to mitigate the issue, but this throws an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What's the actual error output?  Have you tried `sortable: 'LOWER(my_models_table_name.name)'`?

Comment: Try 'my_model.name.to_s.downcase'

Answer (score 1):

If you put this in your active_admin.rb:

```
module ActiveAdmin

  class ResourceController < BaseController

    module DataAccess
      def apply_sorting(chain)
        params[:order] ||= active_admin_config.sort_order
        if params[:order] && params[:order] =~ /^(lower_)?([\w\_\.]+)_(desc|asc)$/
          icase = params[:order].to_s.starts_with?('lower_')
          column = $2
          order  = $3
          table  = active_admin_config.resource_column_names.include?(column) ?
            active_admin_config.resource_table_name : nil
          table_column = (column =~ /\./) ? column :
          [table,active_admin_config.resource_quoted_column_name(column)].compact.join(".")

          chain.reorder("#{'lower' if icase}(#{table_column}) #{order}")
        else
          chain # just return the chain
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
column :name, sortable: 'lower_name'
```

This will also work if calling the column method with a block.

Obviously if you happen to have a column that you want to do this with that's named "lower_anything" you may need to tweak.

Comment: That answer worked for me. (Thanks.)

In the answer above, I replaced lower_ with lower__ (double underline). That eliminates the inability to sort on columns whose names start with "lower_”.