# Ignore case sensitivity when sorting alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When I sort the name column of a model in ActiveAdmin, I get output such as the following:

- Apples
- Icicles
- Zebras
- iMacs
- iPhones

where the uppercase and lowercase letters appear to be sorted separately. I prefer to display sorted columns in the following manner:

- Apples
- Icicles
- iMacs
- iPhones
- Zebras

Can someone help me figure out another way to ignore case sensitivity when sorting columns in active admin. I have a postgres db here is the snippet that I have, but doesn't work for some odd reason:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AgencyWorker do
  config.sort_order = "lower(name_asc)"
```

Any  ideas on what would be causing it? It only has to sort about 30 items. (Also, I have referred to the related/possible duplicate questions, but the solution don't work either, and I'm not sure why as the logic seems good. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore case when sorting a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251099/how-to-ignore-case-when-sorting-a-column)

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/5b711b6e22230e6e28be2a9d7367e9423d5dcc25/lib/active_admin/resource.rb and https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/a473cb68baee260021957ba3d6c3398459a4c551/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb tell us that ActiveAdmin builds its own SQL for `config.sort_order`

There's an issue that describes some solutions here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/642

Comment: hmm interesting, okay. I also just made an edit to add more detail to my problem, not sure if it will change your answer though, but thanks for the links!

Comment: updated with an actual answer; i really, really need coffee.

Comment: Every time I tried to make a comment, you made an edit haha! Sadly, none of the solutions worked, but I will keep trying to figure it out. Thanks for your help